# How to get "property missing" error messages with empty (and thus unsealed) objects

Tags: javascript, flowtype

So, I have an API that takes an options object, something like this:

```js
type Options = { pos: number };

function doTheThing(options: Options) {
}
```

Now, if I call this with any of the below, I get a nice error message:

```
doTheThing(); // requires another argument.
doTheThing({ something: 20 }); // missing property "pos"
```

Great. But if I pass an empty object, Flow will consider this "unsealed" and thus have no issue with it:

```
doTheThing({ }); // No error, would like it to say "pos" missing instead.
```

So, I tried making it exact:

```js
type Options = {| pos: number |};
```

Now, I get an error, but it's not very nice:

```js
doTheThing({ }); //  Cannot call `doTheThing` with object literal bound to `options` because inexact object literal [1] is incompatible with exact `Options` [2].
```

But I just want it to say "pos" is missing. The above is more complicated and just forces you to have to read the definition of `Options` in order to know what it takes. I want it to offer the actual missing property to you. Which it will do, as soon as I put any random thing in there:

```js
doTheThing({ x: 10 }); //  Cannot call `doTheThing` with object literal bound to `options` because property `pos` is missing in object literal [1] but exists in `Options`
```

Is there any way to get it to give me that error message on `{}`, instead of the less useful message? Ideally through some sort of extra annotation on the type and not some global flow configuration that like turns off unsealed objects or something.